# Is it possible to halt a running DLR/IronPython/IronRuby script

Tags: ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I have an application that executes user generated IronRuby scripts where each thread executes on its own thread. The issue I have is that certain events can occur that require the IronRuby script to be stopped at an arbitrary point in the script.

I can do it by aborting the thread the script is running on but that approach has introduced a memory leak into the application. After many months of investigation I have not been able to rectify except by scheduling automatic restarts of the application process. Consequently I am keen to move away from the use of Thread.Abort.

Is there any way to halt an IronRuby script from outside of the script?

The only other idea I can think of is to split each user's script into separate lines and insert a new line after the each script line that checks whether the script should halt but that is bound to introduce syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is currently No :(.

[DLR Interrupt Execution Feature](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=62052)